# how to count the number of cascaded item if ever delete happens in django orm

Tags: django, orm

I want to mass delete in ORM django level but i want to see or simulate the impact of cascaded instance that connected to it. Thanks in advance

Comment: `i want to see or simulate the impact of cascaded ` what do you mean by "seeing"?

Comment: You can try defining your delete() or pre_delete() and implementing your own logging. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you perform `delete()` method of Model, you can `print` returned value of `delete()` method.

```py
instance = Model.objects.get(pk=1)
val = instance.delete() # returns tuple object
print(val) # this will give you all information
```

Or before you delete something, You can count all related objects (Reverse `ForeignKey`) save result in variable and then delete.

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: @Ivan. I want to see the possible impact or the number of rows affected from another model which is dependent of the specific data i will going to delete.